# Set up `cron` job and mailto on error, on Arch

Tags: linux, bash, email, cron

I use `postfix` linked to an commercial smtp server for `cron` jobs to send their owners an email in case of error/warning.
This is a one box Arch setup.

`postfix` works. So does `cronie`.  But although the simplest of all cron jobs  does fire, I get an email from the cron daemon at every execution, which reads:

> /bin/sh: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input.

The cron rule, to be run every minute as a test, is:

```
MAILTO=MYUSERNAME@LOCALHOSTNAME

* * * * * eval "export $(grep -Ez DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";/home/USERNAME/test
```

and the executable ~/test is basically:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/notify-send 'Hello world!' --icon=dialog-information
```

I understand that `grep -Ez [...]` introduces a null byte, as is made necessary by its output with some unusual characters.

My toy example would function properly, if it weren't for that specific warning being emailed to USERNAME at every execution. How do I get rid of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research.... it turns out that `grep -Ez [...]` is not the right way of doing this in a cron job.

`/proc/[pid]/environ` in Linux OS has the quirk that the null byte is the record separator, so that its content when output to stdout "looks" like a single line, i.e. with no EOL character:

```
$ cat -v /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IE.UTF-8^@LC_PAPER=en_IE.UTF-8^@LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8^@LANG=en_US.UTF-8^@GDM_LANG=en_US.UTF-8^@DISPLAY=:1^@USERNAME=USERNAME^@MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins^@XDG_VTNR=2^@XDG_SESSION_ID=2^@USER=USERNAME^@DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome^@PWD=/home/USERNAME^@HOME=/home/USERNAME^@XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11^@XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome^@LC_NUMERIC=en_IE.UTF-8^@MAIL=/var/spool/mail/USERNAME^@WINDOWPATH=2^@SHELL=/bin/bash^@XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME^@XDG_SEAT=seat0^@SHLVL=0^@GDMSESSION=gnome^@LOGNAME=USERNAME^@DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus^@XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000^@XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority^@PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl^@LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8^@
```

In the above, I used `cat` with the `-v` flag to reveal nul bytes.

So the solution is to look for the pattern `"DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"` while recognizing null bytes. `awk` and `gawk` both do that although it is [not portable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html#gawk-split-records), by changing the record separator to the hexadecimal code for the nul byte: `\x00`

```
$ awk -F 'BEGIN {RS="\x00"} /DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS/' /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

That actually produces a clean output with no nul bytes and is well liked by `cron`. No warning is produced and no email is sent.

Comment: As your system uses the "user bus" style in /run, rather than a random session bus address in /tmp, this whole greppage is now optional and you can safely hardcode the bus address. (Or even rely on recent libdbus already having it coded as a default when the environment variable is missing.)

Comment: @grawity: I absolutely did not know that. Would you like to write a simple answer to that effect, so others may actually not miss your comment. Just bear in mind that I was looking for portability, across Linux systems, something my answer does not quite acheive.... Tx.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\0` with `\n`:

```
eval "export $(tr -s \\0 \\n </proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME -x gnome-session)/environ|grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)";/usr/bin/notify-send 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Good idea IporSircer but even replacing "icewm" with something like "gnome-session" produces output very close to mine but with a "D" character at the beginning of the line. I would also tend to favor my posted solution because it lacks your `pipe`, but that's no big deal.

Comment: It was a mistake, updated.

Comment: .... "-x".... ?